# ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API authentication using Azure AD, Membership (Identity)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2, azure-active-directory

I need to build an MVC 5 with Web API 2 app, that will use Single Sign On for authenticating Azure AD users (domain username and password) and external users using membership (identity) username and password or facebook, microsoft, gmail and so forth.

I know how to do it for membership (identity) using username and password + facebook, google or microsoft account but i'm stuck at the Single Sign On for Azure AD users ... how can I combine all of these into my project?

Another thing is that WEB API uses Bearer token for authentication, so that should be kept in mind.

EDIT:

So basically the application is:

- used internally (intranet) authentication should be SSO using AD username and password
- used over the internet authentication is done using username and password or google, facebook, microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [ADAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/3.1.203031538-alpha). You can read all about it on [Vittorio Bertocci's blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/?s=adal).

Answer (score 0):

ADAL is useful to obtain AccessTokens when calling a protected resource.
Katana supports sigining in from FB, Google, AzureAD (using OpenIdConnect or WsFed) and any other Federation provider that supports OIDC or WsFed.

Katana is here:
http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/

Lots of samples here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples